# Symfony assert: Type is array of str, which each str being check using regex

Tags: regex, symfony, validation, assert

Just wanted to know if this kind of assert exist in symfony (If not I will create it for my project).

Like I have an assert

```
#[AssertArrayRegex('/[0-9]{2}/')]
public array $variables = [];
```

This array would be validated

```
$array = [
'12',
'13'
]
```

But not this one

```
$array = [
'12',
'1'
]
```

Comment: The `All` constraint might be able to this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put this code on your Entity Class :

```
#[Assert\All([
        new Assert\NotBlank,
        new Assert\Length(min: 2),
])]
$your_variable;
```

Or maybe this one :

```
#[Assert\All([
        new Assert\Regex('/[0-9]{2}/')
])]
$your_variable;
```

Regards